# Check if Google Fit is installed for OnePlus phones

Tags: android

Currently to check if user has `Google Fit` app installed I use following function:

```
private static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.google.android.apps.fitness";

@CheckResult public boolean fitInstalled() {
    try {
        context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(PACKAGE_NAME, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It works very well on all devices, but OnePlus and Xiaomi. Users say that Google Fit is installed, but function still fails. Is there any other ways I could improve this app installed check to work for OnePlus and Xiaomi phones? Feel like it's manufacturer specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following permission in your app's manifest file that was added in [Android R](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R), this way the installed packages will be visible within your app on any device with [Android R](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R) OS.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

Here is a quote from [Developer Android's Package visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) page:

> When an app targets Android 11 (API level 30) or higher and queries
> for information about the other apps that are installed on a device,
> the system filters this information by default. The limited package
> visibility reduces the number of apps that appear to be installed on a
> device, from your app's perspective.
>
> This filtering behavior helps minimize the amount of potentially
> sensitive information that your app doesn't need in order to fulfill
> its use cases, but that your app can still access. Also, filtered
> package visibility helps app stores like Google Play assess the
> privacy and security that your app provides for users. For example,
> Google Play considers the list of installed apps to be personal and
> sensitive user data.
>
> The limited app visibility affects the return results of methods that
> give information about other apps, such as queryIntentActivities(),
> getPackageInfo(), and getInstalledApplications(). The limited
> visibility also affects explicit interactions with other apps, such as
> starting another app's service.
>
> Some packages are still visible automatically. Your app can always see
> these packages in its queries for other installed apps. To view other
> packages, declare your app's need for increased package visibility
> using the  element. The use cases page provides examples for
> common app interaction scenarios.
>
> In the rare cases where the  element doesn't provide adequate
> package visibility, you can use the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission. If
> you publish your app on Google Play, your app's use of this permission
> is subject to approval based on an upcoming policy.